# Como usar dois API em decorator em Appweb Flask

Tags: python, flask, decorator-pattern

Sou novato no mundo da programação e estou querendo me aprofunda em Aplicação web gostaria de tira uma duvida.

fiz um resquests de um dicionario json de dois api diferente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero colocar esse raspagem de dados numa tabela na minha pagina index so que nao estou sabendo fazer isso com dois api.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue meu github com o codigo: https://github.com/Dalmocabral/flask_infinite_flight/tree/master/app

Answer (score 0):

Antes de passar os dados para o render_template é preciso fazer a concatenação das duas respostas ("Expert" e "TS1"). No entanto esta solução não é escalável porque ai quando for para adicionar uma terceira, vai ser necessário fazer mais uma concatenação e por adiante.

Acho que a melhor opção seria fazer o scraping dos dados para uma base de dados própria da aplicação e o que era passado para o render_template era o resultado de uma query.